# Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Api::V1::TodosController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm following the tutorial here: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-rails-todo-api-part-1 but I end up getting that error when I hit this on my localhost: /api/v1/todos

**routes.rb:**

```
  namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do 
    namespace :v1 do 
      resources :todos 
    end
  end
```

**controllers/api/v1/todos_controller.rb**

```
module Api
    module V1
        class TodosController < ApplicationController
            skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token 
            respond_to :json 

            def index 
                respond_with(Todo.all.order("completed ASC").order("id DESC"))
            end 

            def show 
                @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
                respond_with(@todo)
            end 

            def create 
                @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)
                if @todo.save respond_to do |format| 
                    format.json { render :json => @todo } 
                end 
            end 

            def update
                @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
                if @todo.update(todo_params) 
                    respond_to do |format| 
                        format.json { render :json => @todo } 
                    end
                end
            end

            def destroy
                respond_with Todo.destroy(params[:id])
            end

            private 
                def todo_params
                  params.require(:todo).permit(:title, :completed)
                end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

for some reason there was an end missing. I can't figure out where it's connected to, but throwing an end at the end of the file fixed this error.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
        def create 
            @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)
            if @todo.save respond_to do |format| 
                format.json { render :json => @todo } 
            end 
        end
```

to

```
        def create 
            @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)
            if @todo.save 
                respond_to do |format| 
                   format.json { render :json => @todo } 
                end 
            end
        end
```